# C# scanning COM ports for specific input

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arduino, serial-port

I'm making a program that can control an Arduino board through C#.
Here is the steps the program needs to take:

1. Scan COM Ports
2. Receive inputs from the devices
3. When an input has a specific phrase such as "connectAlready",
4. Close all ports and create a new one on the port that received the phrase.
5. Now that the program knows what COM port the Arduino is on, it can carry on its tasks and send it commands through SerialPorts.

Below is the code i have so far for the connect() method.

```
public void connect()
    {
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        SerialPort[] serialport = new SerialPort[ports.Length];
        foreach(string p in ports)
        {
            int i = Array.IndexOf(ports, p);
            serialport[i].PortName = p;
            serialport[i].BaudRate = 9600;
            serialport[i].Open();
            //Scan inputs for "connectAlready"
        }
```

Not much i know, and i keep getting a "System.NullReferenceException" at serialport[i].PortName = p;

How can I make this program work? Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to declare new serial port object for each serial port which you create:

```
    string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    SerialPort[] serialport = new SerialPort[ports.Length];
    foreach(string p in ports)
    {
        int i = Array.IndexOf(ports, p);
        serialport[i] = new SerialPort(); //note this line, otherwise you have no serial port declared, only array reference which can contains real SerialPort object
        serialport[i].PortName = p; 
        serialport[i].BaudRate = 9600;
        serialport[i].Open();
        //Scan inputs for "connectAlready"
    }
```

And then, you need at least four things to get and to handle your data:

1. Event handler for `DataReceived` for your serial port

   ```
   serialport[i].DataReceived += serialPort_DataReceived; //This is to add event handler delegate when data is received by the port

   private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) { //This is to handle the data when it comes
       //Do something on data received
   }
   ```
2. Get the data from the underlying stream of the port.

   ```
   private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
       SerialPort serialPort1 = sender as SerialPort; 
       byte[] data = new byte[serialPort1.BytesToRead]; //this is to provide the data buffer
       Stream portStream = serialPort1.BaseStream;
       portStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length); //You get your data from serial port as byte[]
       //Do something on your data
   }
   ```
3. `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` to convert the input data from `byte[]` to `ASCII` characters (Edit: consider of changing/skip this step and step 2 if the data received is not `byte[]` but `ASCII`)

   ```
   private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
       SerialPort serialPort1 = sender as SerialPort;
       byte[] data = new byte[serialPort1.BytesToRead]; //this is to provide the data buffer
       Stream portStream = serialPort1.BaseStream;
       portStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length); //You get your data from serial port as byte[]
       string dataString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data); //here is your data in string
       //Do something on your data
   }
   ```
4. Check if the data `string` contains the data that you want

   ```
   bool hasData = dataString.Contains("connectAlready"); //this is to check if your data has this, if it doesn't do something
   ```

And as a last note, beware that the data from your serial port doesn't come together (like "conne" and then "ctAlready"). In such case, you need to copy your received data in a global buffer first then have additional checking (use `Buffer.BlockCopy`)

```
byte[] globalBuffer = new byte[4000]; //large buffer, put globally

//In your data received, use Buffer.BlockCopy to copy data to your globalBuffer
//Beware the index

if (globalBuffer.Length >= 14){ //less than this length, then the data is incomplete
     //Do the checking if length is at least 14
}
```

Comment: If the byte stream is text encoded as ASCII why not document that by using `Encoding.ASCII.GetString`? If it's not known which encoding it is, that's a big problem—and assuming UTF-8 in that case is probably not as good as one of the 256-element character sets that allow every sequence of byte values, with one byte per character (IBM437, ISO-8859-1). Bottom line: When  transmitting text, both sender and receiver have to use an agreed-upon encoding. _There is no text but encoded text._

Comment: its working amazingly, but what value am i supposed to set for the index of globalBuffer?  Buffer.BlockCopy(globalBuffer[]);

Comment: @AmirAbbas declare a variable called `index` and in the `DataReceived` `event`, every time your received `X` bytes you increase `index` by `X`. Similarly, in the `if (length >= 14)`, everytime you get what you need, you can reset the `index` to `0`. And lastly, if you know how to use, you can consider using `Queue<List<byte>>` or `Queue<byte[]>` too. And if your input is already `ASCII`, things can get simpler (see my edit). And you may also use `Queue<string>`. But what I showed you above is the basic flow. Others are all details.

Answer (score 2):

At this Point

```
SerialPort[] serialport = new SerialPort[ports.Length];
```

You are initializing the Array here.
However at this point in for loop,

```
serialport[i].PortName = p;
```

The SerialPort object at that location is not Initialized. Hence the Null Reference Exception

So try adding this in the for loop before assigning anything to Serial port

```
serialport[i]=new SerialPort()
```

Using any constructor you need off-course.